# If URL contains anything, then fire a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, if the URL/`window.location` contains absolutely any variable whatsoever (past domain.com/, of course), I'd like javascript to execute something.

Currently, I have the following jQuery code which only executes when `window.location` contains the exact wording "#hash", but as stated before I'd like to expand the functionality for all variables.

**Edit:** Sorry, to clarify, by variable I mean any one of the following examples:

- domain.com/**#hash**
- domain.com/**#hash2**
- domain.com/**sub/folder**
- domain.com/**textwithoutahash**

*Also, if someone knows how to do this in basic Javascript and without the need for the jQuery library, that would be an added bonus!*

```
$(function() {
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf('#hash') > -1 ) {
        myfunctionhere;
    }
});
```

Comment: Bonus for: "Also, if someone knows how to do this in basic Javascript and without the need for the jQuery library, that would be an added bonus!"

Comment: As written, you don't need the jQuery library.

Comment: $(function() {});

Is actually a jquery shortcut, so, yes you do need jQuery.

Comment: @Andy Dwyer What do you mean by variable in the URL?

Comment: @Салман, I mean anything possible.. for example domain.com/#hash, or domain.com/#work, domain.com/sub/folder/, etc..

Comment: @HighParkCoder No, you don't. There's plenty of vanilla JS alternatives that mirror or come very close to the same functionality

Comment: You could do that without the $(function() {} wrapper

Comment: So you want anything that contains #+'someKeyWord' to execute? Is there a criteria on which function runs? If it's just any value after the hash then simply do `indexOf('#') > -1`.

Comment: You don't want something like `domain.com/?some=variable` too?

Comment: @DennisRongo, not exactly - the URL could also contain a subfolder location, text without a hash, or as Florian Margain pointed out (thank you) a question mark. Basically, if there's absolutely anything past the domain name, I need this Javascript function to execute.

Comment: @Adam but you specifically said "as written, you don't need jQuery".  And I was saying that "as written" he does, since he's using  $(function() {})

Of course it can be written in Vanilla javascript, everything can.  But "AS WRITTEN" above, he needs jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See update at end re your clarification**

Put the script at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>`, and:

If by "variable" you mean a document fragment identifier ("hash"), then:

```
<script>
if (location.hash) {
    callYourFunction();
}
</script>
```

If by "variable" you mean a query string, then

```
<script>
if (location.search) {
    callYourFunction();
}
</script>
```

If by "variable" you mean a resource name, e.g., not `http://domain.com` but `http://domain.com/page`, then:

```
<script>
if (location.pathname && location.pathname !== "/") {
    callYourFunction();
}
</script>
```

More on the location object [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties).

---

Re your clarification:

> Edit: Sorry, to clarify, by variable I mean any one of the following examples:

Those examples come down to having either `hash` or `pathname` or both, so:

```
<script>
if ((location.pathname && location.pathname !== "/") || location.hash) {
    callYourFunction();
}
</script>
```

...and of course, if you also wanted to handle `http://domain.com?foo=bar`, then add in `search` as well:

```
<script>
if ((location.pathname && location.pathname !== "/") ||
    location.search ||
    location.hash) {

    callYourFunction();
}
</script>
```

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: I'm not following you. `hash` works reliably regardless of whether there's a resource name, and the hash is not included in `search` or `pathname`.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks. Yeah, at first I took the word "variable" too literally and assumed `search`. :-)

Comment: Well, I meant that if OP wants "anything", he has to check for all 3 (search, pathname, hash). And my comment was just for the third case, my bad.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha yeah, I assumed a lot too. It would've been nice if we had gotten the information beforehand that is _now_ in the question from these edits

Comment: Well, after your last edits, I'd better recommend my answer :P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for sticking with me throughout my edits. It's late here and my brain isn't working very well... I will try your code and report back in a few minutes. Thanks again

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've tried implementing the last script in your answer and Javascript is firing the function even when there is no variable (hash/query/path/etc) after the trailing domain slash. For example, if I navigate to http://www.domain.com the Javascript is firing the code.

Comment: @AndyDwyer: Well, all you need to do is use a debugger (all modern browsers have one built in) and set a breakpoint on the condition and look at the values to see why. Turns out that `pathname` is `/` when there's no path, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: @AndyDwyer I'd recommend this solution, since the `filter` function I use in my answer doesn't work in IE8. You could add a shim or use jQuery's filter, but TJ's answer is good enough to not need an external dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if there is a `hash`, a `pathname` or a `search`.

Or, to simplify, you could simply use this:

```
if (window.location.href.split('/').filter(Boolean).length > 2) {
    callYourFunction();
}
```

`window.location.href` is simply the whole URL. If there's something after the domain, it'll be shown.

This function will be triggered for the following cases:

- domain.com/some/path
- domain.com/#hash
- domain.com/?some=variable

Comment: "simplify"? I think not. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, I'm just checking one property :P

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `search` property of `window.location` is set to something. Also, you can check the `hash` property:

```
if (window.location.search || window.location.hash) {
  yourfunctionhere();
}
```

To invoke it without jQuery, just include it in an 'onload' script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.onload = function () {
    if (window.location.search || window.location.hash) {
      yourfunctionhere();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This only includes `?key=value` and `#hash`...not `/path/to/page`

Comment: the /path/to/page wasn't clearly mentioned in the original post :)